# Enable/disable task manager history via the cmd prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying test if I can enable/disable task manager history via the cmd prompt.

I can get as far as: `wevtutil set-log Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational` which works perfectly and shows logging is `enabled:true`

However when I try to add the `/enabled:true` or `/enabled:false` switch to the end I get `Invalid option enabled. Option is not supported. The parameter is incorrect.`

I've tried playing with the spacing after `enabled:` adding a space changes the error message to `Too many arguments are specified. The parameter is incorrect`

I've also had a read at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil and this seems like I'm doing this correctly, but it is still throwing up the error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you placed the `/enabled` option? have you also tried the short form `/e`?

Comment: These commands work for me (Win 10 1903) - maybe it depends which version of Windows you're running.

Comment: @aschipfl at the end, tried the short forms too no luck.

Comment: @AmbroseLeung good point, using win7.